# Why does java.io.Reader lock?

Tags: java

`java.io.Reader` has a `lock` field, which it [documents](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#lock) as

> The object used to synchronize operations on this stream.

What is the reason for synchronizing operations on the stream?  The documentation doesn't seem to explain.  I can only think of contrived cases where multiple threads would concurrently read from the same `Reader`.

I see that the JDK's subclasses of `Reader` synchronize all read operations on the lock, for example [`java.io.BufferedReader#read()`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#L171C1-L171C1).  However, some popular libraries that extend `Reader` don't, for example Apache Commons IO (e.g. [`BoundedReader`](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedReader.java#L123)) and parts of Guava (e.g. [`MultiReader`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/MultiReader.java#L54)).  The issue trackers of those projects don't appear to have any mention of problems caused by the lack of synchronization.

Comment: Why is "multiple threads would concurrently read from the same `Reader`" a "contrived" case? Isn't it desirable to have a thread safe reader?

Comment: and it is not only reading, there also is `mark()`, `reset()`, `skip()`, `ready()`, and even `close()` - specially `close()` is a candidate to be called from a different thread than reading

Comment: @Sweeper, each reading thread would get an arbitrary snippet of the character stream.  Getting "lo W" from a stream of "Hello World" doesn't seem very useful.  If  [supplementary characters](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/supplementary.html#:~:text=Supplementary%20characters%20are%20characters%20in,in%20the%20Java%20programming%20language.) are encountered, the snippet a thread reads might cut a multi-byte boundary, meaning it couldn't even be interpreted.  If the cases where reading from multiple threads are all unusual, I'd expect external synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having synchronization support (via the lock field) is related to the potential for multiple threads accessing the same Reader instance concurrently.

For example, if the Reader is reading from a shared file or network stream, proper synchronization prevents conflicts when multiple threads try to read from the same source simultaneously.

For the lack of issues, my best guess would be that single-threaded environments are used mostly with this Reader. Then you do not explicitly worry about synchronization aspects.